# Static analysis using ESLint with snapshot

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, eslint, snapshot, timeline

We're using ESLint in our company in order to detect errors, that break the build and block the deploy, but we also have some other rules which trigger some warnings in our console.

We want to see those warnings in a timeline, so we'll be able to check if we are improving our tech debts or not.

I tried [SonarEsLintPlugin](https://github.com/sleroy/SonarEsLintPlugin) in SonarQube but it does not work properly in version 7+

Anyone knows other way to have ESLint timeline snapshots?

Comment: what about this? https://github.com/groupe-sii/sonar-web-frontend-plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the official [SonarJS plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJs) from SonarSource. In the latest 4.2 version it supports import of ESLint issues, see [documentation here](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/blob/master/docs/DOC.md#import-of-eslint-issues).

It will allow to track your technical debt, you can also import your test coverage, etc. There is also SaaS offering on https://sonarcloud.io